# How to convert datatable into json in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
ArrayList MainData = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    MainData.Add(new { i = datatable.Rows[i][0].ToString() });
}
```

In this above code datatable has 3 record like Mango,Apple,Banana. when i am pushing this datatable into array list called MainData  then maindata should be like this json format... kindly help

```
   "streamData": [
      {
        "0": "Mango"
      },
      {
        "1": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "2": "Banana"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to serialize a DataTable to json or xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458847/how-to-serialize-a-datatable-to-json-or-xml)

Comment: [tag:asp.net-mvc-4] is quite old, released 15 August 2012 according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC#Release_history).  Can you confirm you're using this version?  Different versions use different JSON serializers, so the precise version matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ArrayList MainData = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MainData.Add(new { id = i, fruit = datatable.Rows[i][0].ToString() });
            }
```